# How can I wrap a javascript object property in a function programmatically?

Tags: javascript

assume I have an object:

```
{
  prop: somefunc()
}
```

Now I want to grab the prop's value part: `somefunc()` and wrap it in a function and return the value:

```
function(){
  return somefunc()
}
```

How can I do this programmatically ??

Comment: `somefunc()` *executes* that function and assigns whatever its return value is to `prop`. Given this, it's very unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: `var x = { prop: somefunc }; function somefunc(){(console.log(1))}  x.prop();` I guess you need something like this

Comment: `function(){
  return ObjName.prop.somefunc()
}` assuming `somefunc` is function expression..

Answer (score 1):

Mabye something like this:

It returns a function with a preassigned property and calls the property's function later.

```js
function getPropFn(obj) {
    return function () {
        return obj.prop();
    }
}

var obj = { prop: function () { return 42; } },
    fn42 = getPropFn(obj),
    fn42a = obj.prop; // without fancy stuff.

document.write(fn42() + '<br>' + fn42a());
```

Comment: That's some interesting Javascript acrobatics, but I really struggle to find a practical application for this.